# What are the 'hidden' parts of Paris worth visiting/experiencing?

Tags: paris

After living in Paris for nearly three years I am about to move back to London in two months time. I'd like to do a few new things before I go and would welcome any suggestions that aren't the usual tourist/guidebook fair. Restaurants, museums, streets, tours, markets - anything!

Comment: Hi @camden_kid and welcome to Travel SE. Unfortunately, I had to close vote your question since it is very broad and has no objective correct answer. This is not allowed according to our FAQs. Could you elaborate more on the things you're interested?

Comment: This risks to be complicated as we don't know what you have done and seen during these three years ;-)

Comment: I can't really answer your question as RoflcoptrException explains, but I can suggest a tool for exploring the city in an unconventional way: http://deriveapp.com/app (Disclosure: my app).

Comment: Please do add more detail.  As @RoflcoptrException explains, it's too broad and can't be answered correctly.  I'm closing it for now, but if you add some detail about stuff you're interested in, how much time you have - the more detail the better, and flag to reopen, then we can try and get some answers for you :)

Comment: @MarkMayo Bonjour tout le monde. It's true that it is a broad question but I am looking for a range of unusual recommendations. I don't mind if the question is closed.

Comment: I have always liked the Tour d'Argent restaurant and would recommend it, but definitely insist upon a window seat. I don't know if it's 'hidden paris', but hey, it's great.

Answer (score 2):

There are some 143 [vineyards](http://www.hachette-vins.com/tourisme-vin/route-vins/les-vignobles-d-ile-de-france-de-suresnes-a-paris-9-0.html) in Paris and [Île-de-France](http://wikitravel.org/en/%C3%8Ele-de-France). It could be an idea to visit some of them ...

Have a cruise. The Seine is by far the most famous place for this. However, there are other less "touristic" but not less interesting day cruises you can have in and around Paris: Canal Saint-Martin, Marne, and Canal Saint-Denis. I am aware of [one company](http://www.canauxrama.com/) offering such tours. There might be other ones as well ...